# Debug Dart Application with running rest server

Tags: rest, dart

I need some help on bootstrapping a dart web application.

How can I customize the host and the port against which my dart application is running?

## My scenario

- Running Tomcat with Restful Interface on localhost:8080 (Eg get on localhost/8080/something/entity delivers my a bunch of entities as json)
- DartEditor which should fire httprequests against the tomcat.

## My workaround

Using absolute paths in the urls. Eg http://localhost/8080/something/entity - which is stupid - I would like to have relative paths like /something/entity in my dart application.

Is there a way to start Dartium with the context properly set? Like system params which have to be passed to the debug config.

BR Hubert

Comment: Can you configure tomcat to serve static files and then make a symlink to your dart web folder. Another option is to continue using absolute paths, but pass an environment variable with the test hostname so that you don't have to hardcode it. And only set this at development time. See: String.fromEnvironment().

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the host/port you are running using the `pub serve` command. See here: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-serve.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. In the meantime I got more wisdom and my question got obsolete  :)

My Client application holds customizable properties (host:port/app) which will be used on firing against my REST interface. I like the flexibility of this approach.

BW Hubert